# MySQL Advanced Query multiple AND and OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm drawing a blank this late at night after programming all day and maybe someone else can help shed light on where my issue lies.  I'm trying to make a MySQL query in PHP where it gets the correct fields based on multiple variables using AND and OR.

Here is what I'm trying to do that is not working:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName 
      WHERE key = '$key' ((userFrom = '$userFrom' AND userTo = '$userTo') 
                       OR (userFrom = '$userTo' AND userTo = '$userFrom')");
```

Basically in English what this does is it needs to know the Key value.  Once it matches the key value then I need all the rows with that key value that are ALSO - FROM or TO the same users - think of it as a conversation between two people it has to have their conversation topic (key) and the two participants (from and to).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing an AND between `key = '$key'` and the following parenthesis – is this a typo in your example?

Comment: Yeah I accidentally forgot to type that.  I do have the AND in there in fact and still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like three open parens and two closing parens to me.  The missing one is immediately before the closing double quote.  (Plus, of course, the missing AND mentioned by others).

Also, of course, various characters embedded in user names (if allowed) will make the command fail in data-specific ways.  For that reason, and to avoid SQL Injection attacks, *please* switch to parameterized queries.

Comment: You're correct.  I re-read this another time, evaluated the parameters being POST to my page and realized there was an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a question of getting the parenthesis the correct way.  Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName 
                       WHERE key = '$key' **AND** 
                       ((userFrom = '$userFrom' AND userTo = '$userTo') OR 
                        (userFrom = '$userTo' AND userTo = '$userFrom')");
```

Or perhaps:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName 
                        WHERE ((key = '$key') AND 
                        ((userFrom = '$userFrom' AND userTo = '$userTo') OR 
                         (userFrom = '$userTo' AND userTo = '$userFrom'))");
```

I think if you fiddle with those you will get what you want.

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick.  I've been fiddling around with the positioning of the parenthesis and haven't had much luck strike me quite yet.

Comment: I ran a query with a similar structure (with the extra closing parenthesis that Larry mentioned was missing) and it went off without a hitch.

Comment: Do you have the exact query?  I tried that and didn't work.. Here is my updated query:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatloudChats WHERE ((apiKey = '$apiKey') AND ((userFrom = '$userFrom' AND userTo = '$userTo') OR (userFrom = '$userTo' AND userTo = '$userFrom')))");

Comment: @Brayden, don't show us the php, show us the constructed SQL statement including the data substitution.  Because you are generating dynamic SQL, the contents of the variables matters (see my answer).